# Wrong collisions detection between circle and segment

Tags: c++, rotation, collision-detection, sfml

I'm making an SFML game in C++.

It's a car racing game where the car is been looked at from the top.
The circuit is made of road blocks (square) of 2 different types : straight and corner.

The problem is that the collisions between the car (which has a circle hit box) and the walls around the road (which are segments) aren't properly detected.

The segments are constants initialized with values taken (approximately) from the road blocks.

Then, we rotate the segments around the center of the block in order to allow block rotations.

game is the main loop of the game.
RoadBox defines RoadBlock's hit box.

Collision.hpp:

```
/*
* Definitions of all that are related to collisions:
* -hitBox
* -repulsions
*/
#ifndef DEF_COLLISION_HPP
#define DEF_COLLISION_HPP

#include <SFML/Graphics/Rect.hpp>

class RoadBox;

namespace collision
{
    class RectHitBox
    {
        public:
            RectHitBox();
            RectHitBox(const sf::FloatRect &rect1, float orient1);

            sf::FloatRect rect;
            float orientation;

    };

    class LineHitBox
    {
        public:
            LineHitBox();
            LineHitBox(const sf::Vector2f &point1, const sf::Vector2f &point2);

            void move(const sf::Vector2f &point2);

            sf::Vector2f p1;
            sf::Vector2f p2;
    };

    class CircleHitBox
    {
        public:
            CircleHitBox();
            CircleHitBox(const sf::Vector2f &point, float rayon1);

            sf::Vector2f p;
            float rayon;

    };

    bool collision(const RectHitBox &rectBox1, const RectHitBox &rectBox2);
    bool collision(const RectHitBox &rectBox, const LineHitBox &lineBox);
    bool collisionAsInfiniteLine(const CircleHitBox &cercleBox, const LineHitBox &lineBox);

    //circle and segment
    bool collision(const CircleHitBox &cercleBox, const LineHitBox &lineBox);
    bool collision(const sf::Vector2f &point, const CircleHitBox &cercleBox);
    bool collision(const CircleHitBox &cercleBox1, const CircleHitBox &cercleBox2);

    bool collision(const CircleHitBox &circleBox, const RoadBox &roadBox);

}

#endif
```

Collision.cpp:

```
#include "collision.hpp"
#include "RoadBox.hpp"
#include <cmath> //sqrt needed

#include <iostream>

namespace collision
{

    RectHitBox::RectHitBox()
    {
        orientation = 0;
    }

    RectHitBox::RectHitBox(const sf::FloatRect &rect1, float orient1)
    {
        rect = rect1;
        orientation = orient1;
    }

    LineHitBox::LineHitBox()
    {
        p1 = sf::Vector2f(0, 0);
        p2 = p1;
    }

    LineHitBox::LineHitBox(const sf::Vector2f &point1, const sf::Vector2f &point2)
    {
        p1 = point1;
        p2 = point2;
    }

    void LineHitBox::move(const sf::Vector2f &point2)
    {
        p1 += point2;
        p2 += point2;
    }


    CircleHitBox::CircleHitBox()
    {
        p = sf::Vector2f(0,0);
        rayon = 1;
    }

    CircleHitBox::CircleHitBox(const sf::Vector2f &point, float rayon1)
    {
        p = point;
        rayon = rayon1;
    }

    bool collision(const RectHitBox &rectBox1, const RectHitBox &rectBox2)
    {
        sf::FloatRect rect1 = rectBox1.rect, rect2 = rectBox2.rect;

        /*int centre1_x = rect1.left + rect1.width/ 2;
        int centre1_y = rect1.top + rect1.height/ 2;
        int centre2_x = rect2.left + rect2.width/ 2;
        int centre2_y = rect2.top + rect2.height/ 2;*/

        int dis2centre = (rect1.left-rect2.left)*(rect1.left-rect2.left) + (rect1.top-rect2.top)*(rect1.top-rect2.top); //Distance entre deux centre

        int rayon1 = ((rect1.height * rect1.height) + (rect1.width * rect1.width))/2;
        int rayon2 = ((rect2.height * rect2.height) + (rect2.width * rect2.width))/2;
        return (dis2centre < (rayon1 + rayon2)*(rayon1 + rayon2));
    }

    bool collision(const sf::Vector2f &point, const CircleHitBox &cercleBox)
    {
        sf::Vector2f C(cercleBox.p);
        float x = point.x, y = point.y;
        float rayon = cercleBox.rayon;

        float d2 = (x-C.x)*(x-C.x) + (y-C.y)*(y-C.y);
        if (d2>rayon*rayon)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    bool collisionAsInfiniteLine(const CircleHitBox &cercleBox, const LineHitBox &lineBox)
    {
        sf::Vector2f A(lineBox.p1), B(lineBox.p2), C(cercleBox.p);
        sf::Vector2f u;
        u.x = B.x - A.x;
        u.y = B.y - A.y;

        sf::Vector2f AC;
        AC.x = C.x - A.x;
        AC.y = C.y - A.y;

        float numerateur = u.x*AC.y - u.y*AC.x;
        if(numerateur < 0)
        {
            numerateur = -numerateur;
        }

        float denominateur = std::sqrt(u.x*u.x + u.y*u.y);
        float CI = numerateur / denominateur;
        if(CI < cercleBox.rayon)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    bool collision(const CircleHitBox &cercleBox, const LineHitBox &lineBox)
    {
        sf::Vector2f A(lineBox.p1), B(lineBox.p2), C(cercleBox.p);

        if(!collisionAsInfiniteLine(cercleBox, lineBox))
        {
            return false;
        }

        sf::Vector2f AB,AC,BC;
        AB.x = B.x - A.x;
        AB.y = B.y - A.y;
        AC.x = C.x - A.x;
        AC.y = C.y - A.y;
        BC.x = C.x - B.x;
        BC.y = C.y - B.y;
        float pscal1 = AB.x*AC.x + AB.y*AC.y;  // produit scalaire
        float pscal2 = (-AB.x)*BC.x + (-AB.y)*BC.y;  // produit scalaire
        if (pscal1>=0 && pscal2>=0)
            return true;   // I entre A et B, ok.
        // dernière possibilité, A ou B dans le cercle
        if (collision(A,cercleBox))
            return true;
        if (collision(B,cercleBox))
            return true;
        return false;
    }

    bool collision(const CircleHitBox &cercleBox1, const CircleHitBox &cercleBox2)
    {
        sf::Vector2f C1(cercleBox1.p), C2(cercleBox2.p);
        float d2 = (C1.x-C2.x)*(C1.x-C2.x) + (C1.y-C2.y)*(C1.y-C2.y);
        if (d2 > (cercleBox1.rayon + cercleBox2.rayon)*(cercleBox1.rayon + cercleBox2.rayon))
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }

    bool collision(const CircleHitBox &circleBox, const RoadBox &roadBox)
    {
        bool collided = false;
        const std::vector<collision::LineHitBox> &hitBox = roadBox.getLineArray();

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < hitBox.size() && !collided; i++)
        {
            collided = collision(circleBox, hitBox[i]);
            /*if(collided)
            {
                //std::cout<< "collision\n";
            }*/
        }

        return collided;
    }

} //namespace collision
```

Car.hpp:

```
// A Car shall be drawable and transformable. It can collide with other objects.

#ifndef DEF_CAR_HPP
#define DEF_CAR_HPP

#include <SFML/Graphics/Drawable.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Transformable.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Sprite.hpp>

#include "Timer.hpp"
#include "collision.hpp"

namespace sf
{
    class Texture;
}

class Car : public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable
{
    public:
        Car(sf::Texture &tex, float maxSpeed = 100);


        void accelerate(float accel);

        void rotate(float rot);

        void apply_physics();

        collision::CircleHitBox getHitBox() const;

    protected:
        virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget& target, sf::RenderStates states) const;

    private:
        float norm(const sf::Vector2f &v) const;

        float m_acceleration;
        float m_rotation;

        sf::Sprite m_sprite;

        Timer m_physicTimer; //timer that permit the physics to apply at every frame

        sf::Vector2f m_speedVector;
        float m_maxSpeed;


        float m_hitBoxRadius;
};

#endif
```

Car.cpp :

```
#include "Car.hpp"

#include <SFML/Graphics/Texture.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.hpp>

#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>

Car::Car(sf::Texture &tex, float maxSpeed)
{
    m_acceleration = 0;
    m_rotation = 0;

    m_sprite.setTexture(tex);

    sf::Vector2u texSize(tex.getSize());
    m_sprite.setOrigin(float(texSize.x)/2.f, float(texSize.y)/2.f);
    m_speedVector = sf::Vector2f(0, 0);

    //to take the included circle, take the min btw width and height
    m_hitBoxRadius = 93/2;

    m_maxSpeed = maxSpeed;

    m_physicTimer.setDuration(sf::seconds(1./60.)); //60 fps
    m_physicTimer.restart();

}

void Car::accelerate(float accel)
{
    m_acceleration = accel;
}

void Car::rotate(float rot)
{
    m_rotation = rot;
}

void Car::draw(sf::RenderTarget &target, sf::RenderStates states) const
{
    states.transform *= getTransform();
    //states.transform.rotate(-90); //the car is not well orientated in the loaded image
    target.draw(m_sprite, states);
}

void Car::apply_physics()
{
    if(m_physicTimer.ticked())
    {
        float currentSpeed = norm(m_speedVector);

        sf::Transformable::rotate(m_rotation/**(currentSpeed / m_maxSpeed)*/);
        float rotation = getRotation();

        float accelFactor = m_physicTimer.getFullWaitedDuration().asSeconds();

        //std::cout<< accelFactor * 60<< "\n";

        //calculate the new speed with the acceleration
        m_speedVector.x += std::cos(rotation*M_PI/180)*m_acceleration*accelFactor;
        m_speedVector.y += std::sin(rotation*M_PI/180)*m_acceleration*accelFactor;

        //calculate the new position with the speed
        move(m_speedVector);


        m_acceleration = 6;
        m_physicTimer.restart();

        //std::cout<< getPosition().x<< " ; "<< getPosition().y<< '\n';
        //std::cout<< 60*accelFactor<< '\n';
    }
}

float Car::norm(const sf::Vector2f &v) const
{
    return std::sqrt((v.y*v.y) + (v.x*v.x));
}

collision::CircleHitBox Car::getHitBox() const
{
    return collision::CircleHitBox(getPosition(), m_hitBoxRadius);
}
```

RoadBlock.hpp :

```
#ifndef DEF_ROADBLOCK_HPP   
#define DEF_ROADBLOCK_HPP

#include <SFML/Graphics/Drawable.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Transformable.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/RenderStates.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Texture.hpp>
#include <SFML/System/Vector2.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Sprite.hpp>

#include <string>
#include <vector>

#include "collision.hpp"
#include "RoadBox.hpp"

namespace sf
{
    class RenderTarget;
}

static const std::string STRAIGHT_TEXTURE_NAME("gameData/images/straight.png");
static const std::string CORNER_TEXTURE_NAME("gameData/images/corner1.png");
static const std::string GRASS_TEXTURE_NAME("gameData/images/grass2.png");

class RoadBlock : public sf::Drawable, public sf::Transformable
{
    public:
        enum roadType
        {
            straight = 0, 
            corner = 1
        };

        enum rotation //clockwise
        {
            standard = 0, 
            right= 1, 
            left = 2, 
            down = 3
        };

        RoadBlock();
        RoadBlock(const sf::Texture &texture, roadType t, rotation r, const sf::Vector2f &pos);
        RoadBlock(roadType t, rotation r, const sf::Vector2f &pos = sf::Vector2f(0.0, 0.0));

        rotation getRotation() const;
        roadType getRType() const;

        void setRotation(rotation r);
        void setType(roadType t);

        RoadBox getHitBox() const;

        //standard shared textures
        static const sf::Texture straightTexture;
        static const sf::Texture cornerTexture;
        static const sf::Texture grassTexture;

        //standard shared textures size
        static const sf::Vector2i texSize;

    protected:  
        virtual void draw(sf::RenderTarget &target, sf::RenderStates states) const;

    private:
        sf::Sprite m_sprite;
        roadType m_type;
};

//turn 90° clockwise
RoadBlock::rotation operator++(RoadBlock::rotation &r, int);

//turn -90° clockwise
RoadBlock::rotation operator--(RoadBlock::rotation &r, int);

//change of roadType to the next one
RoadBlock::roadType operator++(RoadBlock::roadType &r, int);

#endif
```

RoadBlock.cpp:

```
#include "RoadBlock.hpp"

#include <SFML/Graphics/RenderTarget.hpp>
#include "FileLoader.hpp"
#include "collision.hpp"

#include <iostream>

const sf::Texture RoadBlock::straightTexture = createFromFile<sf::Texture>(STRAIGHT_TEXTURE_NAME);
const sf::Texture RoadBlock::cornerTexture = createFromFile<sf::Texture>(CORNER_TEXTURE_NAME);
const sf::Texture RoadBlock::grassTexture = createFromFile<sf::Texture>(GRASS_TEXTURE_NAME);

const sf::Vector2i RoadBlock::texSize = sf::Vector2i(256, 256);

RoadBlock::RoadBlock()
{
    m_sprite.setOrigin(float(texSize.x)/2.f, float(texSize.y)/2.f);
}

RoadBlock::RoadBlock(const sf::Texture &texture, roadType t, rotation r, const sf::Vector2f &pos)
{
    setPosition(pos);

    m_sprite.setTexture(texture);
    setType(t);

    m_sprite.setOrigin(float(texSize.x)/2.f, float(texSize.y)/2.f);

    setRotation(r);

    m_sprite.setOrigin(0, 0);
}

RoadBlock::RoadBlock(roadType t, rotation r, const sf::Vector2f &pos)
{
    m_sprite.setOrigin(float(texSize.x)/2.f, float(texSize.y)/2.f);

    setPosition(pos);

    //std::cout<< pos.x<< " ; "<< pos.y<< '\n';

    setRotation(r);
    setType(t);
}

void RoadBlock::setRotation(rotation r)
{
    switch(r)
    {
        case right:
            m_sprite.setRotation(90);
            break;
        case left:
            m_sprite.setRotation(-90);
            break;
        case down:
            m_sprite.setRotation(180);
            break;
        case standard:
            m_sprite.setRotation(0);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    //m_sprite.rotate(10);
}

void RoadBlock::setType(roadType t)
{
    m_type = t;

    switch(t)
    {
        case straight:
            m_sprite.setTexture(RoadBlock::straightTexture);
            break;
        case corner:
            m_sprite.setTexture(RoadBlock::cornerTexture);
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

RoadBlock::rotation RoadBlock::getRotation() const
{
    float r = m_sprite.getRotation();
    std::cout<< r<< '\n';
    switch(int(r))
    {
        case 90:
            return right;
            break;
        case 270:
            return left;
            break;
        case 180:
            return down;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return standard; //shall never be executed
}

RoadBlock::roadType RoadBlock::getRType() const
{
    return m_type;
}

RoadBox RoadBlock::getHitBox() const
{
    return RoadBox(*(this));
}

void RoadBlock::draw(sf::RenderTarget &target, sf::RenderStates states) const
{
    states.transform *= getTransform();
    states.transform.translate(float(texSize.x)/2.f, float(texSize.y)/2.f);

    target.draw(m_sprite, states);
}

RoadBlock::rotation operator++(RoadBlock::rotation &r, int nn)
{
    RoadBlock::rotation ans(r); //answer
    switch(r)
    {
        case RoadBlock::standard:
            r = RoadBlock::right;
            break;
        case RoadBlock::right:
            r = RoadBlock::down;
            break;
        case RoadBlock::down:
            r = RoadBlock::left;
            break;
        case RoadBlock::left:
            r = RoadBlock::standard;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return ans;
}

RoadBlock::rotation operator--(RoadBlock::rotation &r, int nn)
{
    RoadBlock::rotation ans(r); //answer
    switch(r)
    {
        case RoadBlock::standard:
            r = RoadBlock::left;
            break;
        case RoadBlock::right:
            r = RoadBlock::standard;
            break;
        case RoadBlock::down:
            r = RoadBlock::right;
            break;
        case RoadBlock::left:
            r = RoadBlock::down;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return ans;
}

RoadBlock::roadType operator++(RoadBlock::roadType &r, int)
{
    RoadBlock::roadType ans(r);
    switch(r)
    {
        case RoadBlock::straight:
            r = RoadBlock::corner;
            break;
        case RoadBlock::corner:
            r = RoadBlock::straight;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return ans;
}
```

RoadBox.hpp:

```
// A RoadBox is the RoadBlock's hit box.
// It's meant to easy collisions with the cars.

#ifndef DEF_ROADBOX_HPP
#define DEF_ROADBOX_HPP

#include <SFML/Graphics/Transformable.hpp>
#include "collision.hpp"
//#include "RoadBlock.hpp"

#include <vector>

class RoadBlock;

class RoadBox: public sf::Transformable //be careful with SFML transformations, none shall be used from a outside
{
    public:
        RoadBox(const RoadBlock &roadBlock);

        const std::vector<collision::LineHitBox> & getLineArray() const;

        /*
        These variables are initialized on program start.
        They represent the different standard hitBoxes of RoadBlocks.
        */
        static const std::vector<collision::LineHitBox> bigArcHitBox;
        static const std::vector<collision::LineHitBox> smallArcHitBox;
        static const std::vector<collision::LineHitBox> straightHitBox;

    private:
        std::vector<collision::LineHitBox> m_hitBox;

};

#endif //DEF_ROADBOX_HPP
```

RoadBox.cpp:

```
#include "RoadBox.hpp"
#include "RoadBlock.hpp"


/*
All functions defined as static in this file are initializers for RoadBox's static variables (hit boxes).
Therefore there is no mean to give access to these in other files.
*/

namespace pv //private
{
    static std::vector<collision::LineHitBox> getBigArcHitBox();
    static std::vector<collision::LineHitBox> getSmallArcHitBox();
    static std::vector<collision::LineHitBox> getStraightHitBox(); 
}
namespace pv //private
{
    static std::vector<collision::LineHitBox> getBigArcHitBox()
    {
        using namespace collision;

        sf::Vector2f posOffsetToCenter( - RoadBlock::texSize/2);

        std::vector<LineHitBox> hitBox(3);
        hitBox[0] = LineHitBox(sf::Vector2f(31, 256), sf::Vector2f(31, 134));
        hitBox[1] = LineHitBox(sf::Vector2f(31, 134), sf::Vector2f(121, 32));
        hitBox[2] = LineHitBox(sf::Vector2f(121, 32), sf::Vector2f(256, 31));

        //center the hitBox on (0, 0)
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < hitBox.size(); i++)
        {
            hitBox[i].move(posOffsetToCenter);
        }

        return hitBox;
    }

    static std::vector<collision::LineHitBox> getSmallArcHitBox()
    {
        using namespace collision;

        sf::Vector2f posOffsetToCenter( - RoadBlock::texSize/2);

        std::vector<LineHitBox> hitBox(2);
        hitBox[0] = LineHitBox(sf::Vector2f(225, 255), sf::Vector2f(226, 224));
        hitBox[1] = LineHitBox(sf::Vector2f(226, 224), sf::Vector2f(256, 225));

        //center the hitBox on (0, 0)
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < hitBox.size(); i++)
        {
            hitBox[i].move(posOffsetToCenter);
        }

        return hitBox;
    }

    static std::vector<collision::LineHitBox> getStraightHitBox()
    {
        using namespace collision;

        sf::Vector2f posOffsetToCenter( - RoadBlock::texSize/2);

        std::vector<LineHitBox> hitBox(2);
        hitBox[0] = LineHitBox(sf::Vector2f(31, 256), sf::Vector2f(31, 0)/*sf::Vector2f(0, 0), sf::Vector2f(0, 256)*/);
        hitBox[1] = LineHitBox(sf::Vector2f(225, 256), sf::Vector2f(225, 0)/*sf::Vector2f(256, 0), sf::Vector2f(256, 256)*/);

        //center the hitBox on (0, 0)
        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < hitBox.size(); i++)
        {
            hitBox[i].move(posOffsetToCenter);
        }

        return hitBox;
    }

}

const std::vector<collision::LineHitBox> RoadBox::bigArcHitBox = pv::getBigArcHitBox();
const std::vector<collision::LineHitBox> RoadBox::smallArcHitBox = pv::getSmallArcHitBox();
const std::vector<collision::LineHitBox> RoadBox::straightHitBox = pv::getStraightHitBox();

RoadBox::RoadBox(const RoadBlock &roadBlock)
{
    using namespace collision;

    //to get the right hit box, we need to transform the default hit box, because no rotation is in it
    sf::Transform transf;
    transf.rotate(roadBlock.sf::Transformable::getRotation());

    RoadBlock::roadType t = roadBlock.getRType();
    switch(t)
    {
        case RoadBlock::straight:
            m_hitBox.resize(straightHitBox.size());
            for(unsigned int i = 0; i < m_hitBox.size(); i++)
            {
                m_hitBox[i] = LineHitBox
                (
                    transf.transformPoint(straightHitBox[i].p1)
                    ,transf.transformPoint(straightHitBox[i].p2)
                );
            }
            break;
        case RoadBlock::corner:
            m_hitBox.resize(bigArcHitBox.size() + smallArcHitBox.size());
            for(unsigned int i = 0; i < bigArcHitBox.size(); i++)
            {
                m_hitBox[i] = LineHitBox
                (
                    transf.transformPoint(bigArcHitBox[i].p1)
                    ,transf.transformPoint(bigArcHitBox[i].p2)
                );
            }
            for(unsigned int i = 0; i < smallArcHitBox.size(); i++)
            {
                m_hitBox[i] = LineHitBox
                (
                    transf.transformPoint(smallArcHitBox[i].p1)
                    ,transf.transformPoint(smallArcHitBox[i].p2)
                );
            }
            break;
        default: //shall never be used
            break;

    }

    //place the calculated hit boxes at the right position
    sf::Vector2f pos(roadBlock.getPosition());
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < m_hitBox.size(); i++)
    {
        m_hitBox[i].p1 += pos;
        m_hitBox[i].p2 += pos;
    }
}

const std::vector<collision::LineHitBox> & RoadBox::getLineArray() const
{
    return m_hitBox;
}
```

game.cpp :

```
#include "game.hpp"

#include <SFML/Graphics/RenderWindow.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window/Event.hpp>
#include <SFML/Window/Keyboard.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/Texture.hpp>
#include <SFML/Graphics/View.hpp>

#include <iostream>

#include "Map.hpp"
#include "Timer.hpp"
#include "OpenFileError.hpp"

namespace game
{
    Action::Action(float orien, int accel): 
        orientation(orien), acceleration(accel)
    {
    }

    void getEvents(sf::RenderWindow &window, Action &action)
    {
        action.acceleration = 0;
        action.orientation = 0;
        sf::Event event;
        while(window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            switch(event.type)
            {
                case sf::Event::Closed:
                    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                    break;
                case sf::Event::KeyPressed:
                    switch(event.key.code)
                    {
                        case sf::Keyboard::Escape:
                            exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
                            break;
                        default:
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case sf::Event::KeyReleased:
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Down))
        {
            action.acceleration = -5;
        }
        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Up))
        {
            action.acceleration = 5;
        }
        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Right))
        {
            action.orientation = 5;
        }
        if(sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Left))
        {
            action.orientation = -5;
        }

    }

    void game(sf::RenderWindow &window)
    {
        //view that will follow the car
        sf::View carView(sf::FloatRect(0, 0, 800, 600));
        //carView.setSize(640, 480);
        window.setView(carView);

        //image loading
        sf::Texture texPlayerCar;
        if(!texPlayerCar.loadFromFile(CAR_FILE))
        {
            throw OpenFileError();
        }

        Map map(std::string("saveMap.pwet"));

        std::cout<< map.begin()->getPosition().x<< " ; "<< map.begin()->getPosition().y<< '\n';

        Car playerCar(texPlayerCar, 50); //50 = max speed
        playerCar.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(RoadBlock::texSize/2));

        //other variables
        Action action;

        Timer loopTimer(sf::seconds(1./60.)); //60 fps
        //std::cout<< loopTimer.getDuration().asSeconds()<< '\n';
        loopTimer.restart();

        int j = 0; //count the number of collisions (max 1 each frame)

        //main loop
        while(true)
        {
            getEvents(window, action);

            //game physic/////////////////////////////
            playerCar.accelerate(action.acceleration);  
            playerCar.rotate(action.orientation);

            playerCar.apply_physics();

            //collisions tests
            bool collided = false;
            int i = 0;
            for(Map::iterator it = map.begin(); it != map.end() && !collided; it++)
            {   
                collided = collision::collision(playerCar.getHitBox(), it->getHitBox());
            }
            if(collided)
            {
                std::cout<< ++j<<"\n";
            }

            // \game physics /////////////////////////

            //game display////////////////////////////
            carView.setCenter(playerCar.getPosition());
            window.setView(carView);

            window.clear(sf::Color::Black);

            window.draw(map);
            window.draw(playerCar);

            window.display();

            // \game display//////////////////////////

            //time handling///////////////////////////

            loopTimer.autoSleep();

            // \time handling/////////////////////////  
        }

    }

    void loadCars(std::vector<Car> &carsTab, std::vector<sf::Texture> &texTab)
    {
        try
        {
            sf::Texture texCar;
            if(!texCar.loadFromFile(CAR_FILE))
            {
                OpenFileError error;
                throw error;
            }

            texTab.push_back(texCar);
            carsTab.push_back(Car(texTab[0], CAR_SPEED));
        }
        catch(std::exception &except)
        {
            std::cerr<< except.what()<< "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

I'm giving you an example of what is the problem, as suggested by Anon Mail.

I uncommented the following lines in collision.cpp:

```
bool collision(const CircleHitBox &circleBox, const RoadBox &roadBox)
    {
        bool collided = false;
        const std::vector<collision::LineHitBox> &hitBox = roadBox.getLineArray();

        for(unsigned int i = 0; i < hitBox.size() && !collided; i++)
        {
            collided = collision(circleBox, hitBox[i]);
            if(collided) //These ones, from here ...
            {
                std::cout<< "collision\n";
            } //... to here
        }

        return collided;
    }
```

starting at line 161

Then I made the debugger do his job. I only started the game, and pressed the down button until finding the breakpoint in the function that tests collisions between circle and roadBoxes.

```
(gdb) break collision.cpp:171
Breakpoint 1 at 0x404577: file collision.cpp, line 171.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /home/victor/projetCarRacing/carRacing 
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
[New Thread 0x7fffeeebe700 (LWP 2878)]
0 ; 0

Breakpoint 1, collision::collision (circleBox=..., roadBox=...) at collision.cpp:171
171                 std::cout<< "collision\n";
(gdb) print circleBox 
$1 = (const collision::CircleHitBox &) @0x7fffffffd740: {p = {x = 75,2980652, y = 128}, rayon = 46}
(gdb) print hitBox[i]
$2 = {p1 = {x = 31, y = 256}, p2 = {x = 31, y = 0}}
```

I guess you'll need an image to fully understand what is happening.
Remember one thing : The radius of the car's hit box is the car's width : 46 px.
The line on the road at the back of the car is not a wall. It shall not have a hit box.

[image: game screenshot]

I'll need to add that most of game.hpp/cpp is not that much relevant here.
Only the part that tests collisions shall perhaps be useful:

```
            //collisions tests
            bool collided = false;
            int i = 0;
            for(Map::iterator it = map.begin(); it != map.end() && !collided; it++)
            {   
                collided = collision::collision(playerCar.getHitBox(), it->getHitBox());
            }
            if(collided)
            {
                //some stuff...
            }
```

Comment: Post relevant code here, instead of link.

Comment: Please post a MCVE: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Added the code as you guys asked me to, thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: Just to say, are you sure this `return` expression actually returns the right value: `return (dis2centre < (rayon1 + rayon2)*(rayon1 + rayon2));`? Try adding a pair of brackets: `return (dis2centre < ((rayon1 + rayon2)*(rayon1 + rayon2)));`

Comment: Same thing, problem's not probably here... any other ideas in the collision algorithm itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all thank you from those who took time on our work.
I managed to solve the problem by myself.

There were in fact a lot of errors in our code, in RoadBox::RoadBox:

1. I forgot a break instruction (stupid error, yes)
2. I didn't modified the good values in m_hitBox
3. when using transformations to rotate the hitBox, I used the wrong function sf::Transform::rotate. It should have been the one with a center as argument, but I took the other one. It worked only because the standard hitboxes were centered around (0, 0).

Finally I'll explain the last error I met, because it was funny:
When testing collisions with a corner block and the car, a call of gdb told me that bigArcHitBox values were here, but instead of smallArcHitBox values, were straightHitBox values !
In fact, I just went too far in smallArcHitBox. But if you look at RoadBox.hpp/cpp files, straightHitBox is stored just after smallArcHitBox. So I ended with no segment fault, but wrong values that came from the wrong spot.

Have a nice day!

Comment: Ah sorry, I'm not that good at English ^^. In france we say it when working in a group, even if only one person was involved at a time.

Comment: Oh, that's another case that works in English – when you're the spokesperson for a group. However, since you said "I" all through your question, I assumed you weren't. And no worries! My English ain't all that great either.